# Symfony bundle config import - expand/merge 2 sequences

Tags: symfony, yaml, config, sequence, expand

There's a configuration in the PHP Symfony 6.3 application defined as

```
->arrayNode('main_list')->scalarPrototype()
```

Now to this config I want to import following bundle yamls:

`@BundleOneBundle/Resources/config/list.yaml`

```
parameters:
    bundle_one_list:
        - 'value one of bundle BundleOne'
        - 'value two of bundle BundleOne'
```

`@BundleTwoBundle/Resources/config/list.yaml`

```
parameters:
    bundle_two_list:
        - 'value one of bundle BundleTwo'
        - 'value two of bundle BundleTwo'
```

Now if I would only want to assign 1 of the sequences it would be easy:

```
imports:
    - { resource: '@BundleOneBundle/Resources/config/list.yaml'  }
    - { resource: '@BundleTwoBundle/Resources/config/list.yaml' }

app_config:
    main_list: '%bundle_one_list%'
```

But how to put both there so they are still 1 sequence?

**Is there some way to expand them directly? or merge them into one without alias hacks?**

**So it would be an equivalent of:**

```
app_config:
    main_list:
        - 'value one of bundle BundleOne'
        - 'value two of bundle BundleOne'
        - 'value one of bundle BundleTwo'
        - 'value two of bundle BundleTwo'
```

?

Note that defining a list of lists is not an option here, but if you can, the solution is to define the field as `arrayPrototype` and then you can just

```
main_list:
    - '%bundle_one_list%'
    - '%bundle_two_list%'
# or
main_list: ['%bundle_one_list%', '%bundle_two_list%']
```